# JMX RuntimeException operation failed with status waiting

Tags: java, jmx

I am trying to run the Oracle JMX example, consisting of an agent and a client. The Agent runs perfectly, but when I try to run the client I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.connect(RemotingConnector.java:154)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:227)
    at com.example.Client.main(Client.java:61)
```

this is the part of the code where it goes wrong:

```
        String host = "localhost";
    int port = 9999;
    String urlString = System.getProperty("jmx.service.url","service:jmx:remoting-jmx://" + host + ":" + port);
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(urlString);
    JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
```

Does anyone know what may have cause this?

Comment: you ever work this out?

Comment: would also love to know!

Comment: Sorry guys, I can't remember exactly how I solved it. Or if I even solved it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is a very old question but I recently ran into the same problem.

In my case, updating the connector to use http protocol found the connection successfully. 'remoting-jmx' has also been deprecated (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-579) and should be updated to 'remote' :

```
String host = "localhost";
int port = 9999;
String urlString = System.getProperty("jmx.service.url","service:jmx:remote+http://" + host + ":" + port);
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(urlString);
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
```